# SSH keys on both Windows 10 and WLinux

Tags: linux, windows-10, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have a Windows 10 Pro installation. I have installed WSL WLinux Distro. I am trying to use SSH keygen generation per the GitLab SSH keygen page.

Everything goes fine. The key is created under id_rsa.pub, and then I try to copy the thing. I used xclip which is installed. And I get:
`Cannot open display of null`. I tried the Windows option as well, 
`cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`. Didn't work either.

I tried a lot of solution online. They don't do anything. Has anyone done this, with WLinux distribution.

**UPDATE:**
I used the guide [here](https://florianbrinkmann.com/en/3436/ssh-key-and-the-windows-subsystem-for-linux/). This is for Ubuntu and the latest Windows 10 Versions, which I am running, but I use a different distribution `WLinux` in this case.

The cp, command , I haven't tried yet. I was able to get the content of the -d_rsa.pub file using vim. The problem is I need a more secure config, in the future.

Comment: Either one or the other. I would prefer to be able to do it from both. But WSL is a priority. So, I would like to be able to use SSH from wsl.

Comment: I want to add the key to my work GitLab account. I also have 2 more SSH keys I need to connect to GitLab and GitHub accordingly. I also, don't get. If you don't care about security, SSH keys are exactly for that reason, convenience as well, but mainly security. Please elaborate..

Comment: OK. To understand you issue, could you add some info? Which instruction did you follow, any link? Do you want to make WSL accessible from outside world? Copy from where to where? Did you try with simple `cp` command to copy? Thank you.

Comment: I added a small update section. As far as accessing it goes, I just want to be able to clone, push, and etc... inside WSL. Everything else, can come later.. Thanks!!